# How can I get PyGame to work with VSCode?

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

I already have installed the pygame package and get this error :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

Comment: (1) You should post your answer as an answer. This is not a general forum. (2) You don't need to change your PATH; you can just change the interpreter used in VSCode. (3) PyGame 2.x has wheels (binary packages) available for up to Python 3.10, so unless you insist on pygame 1.9.x, you don't need to downgrade your Python.

Comment: I tried literally everything for the past week and this is the only thing that has worked for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue I had for like a week now however I have found something that works with me and hopefully it works with you!

If you already have installed the pygame package and get this error :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

***Try to debug your python file and hopefully the error wont appear. Also, make sure to not "Run Code" but instead "Run Python File". To do this at the top right corner should be a play button press that an select "Run Python File".***

You can test your pygame with this code that will open up a blank pygame window:

```
import pygame


WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600


WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))


def main():
    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get ():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**If the above doesn't work then try to upgrade or downgrade your python version and pygame version to:**

Python: 3.7.4(32-bit)

Pygame: 1.9.6

**To change python version:**

1. Go to *https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/* and scroll down till you find Python 3.7.4 and download the "Download Windows x86 executable installer"
2. Install pyhton
3. Add python to PATH

- WINDOWS + R
- sysdm.cpl
- Advanced > Enviroment Variables > Path > Edit
- Add the following to path on User Variable and System Variable
- C:\Users\*user*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts
- C:\Users\*user*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32

**To install pygame version 1.9.6:**

1. WINDOWS + R
2. CMD
3. Enter the following

> pip install pygame==1.9.6
> 4. To double check if version is correct
> pip show pygame

*Ensure to "Run Python File" and ***not*** "Run Code"*

Hopefully this has helped!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).